# What's the difference between these two phrases

Tags: meaning

I saw two phrases 'come to one's rescue' and 'come to one's assistance'. What's the difference between them?Thank you.

Comment: Kuu A, did you try a dictionary? :) I believe the only similarity between 'rescue' and 'assistance' is both appearing in that set phrase.

Comment: I just want to know the difference between the two phrases. I had to chose one of them to complete my sentence in my homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rescue** is [to save someone or something from a dangerous, harmful, or difficult situation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rescue)

**Assistance** is to provide help or support, typically meaning in the sense of resources ([see for example](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assistance)).

Comment: What good does spoonfeeding the answer to the learner do, rather than teaching them to fish from the dictionary? :(

Comment: @M.A.R., I generally agree, but I could see where someone might find the two phrases similar enough to be confusing.  Looking back on the answer, though, I didn't really add much to what could be found in a dictionary search, so you're probably right.

Comment: Please [do not feed the bears](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236/).

Comment: @ColleenV & M.A.R., I'm still learning my way around the site's norms.  Thanks for the education.  :-)

Comment: If no-one explains it, how will you know? Well, unless you're a mind reader ;) There is a big gray area, but in general if you're having a hard time writing more than the dictionary definition, it may be worth trying to improve the question instead of answering.